# How to keep newest version of binary files on GitHub without fully tracking them?

Tags: git, github

I'd like to keep the newest version of some binary files (i.e. pdf, jpg, png) up to date on my GitHub via the `git add`/`commit`/`push` workflow that I know. But I have no need for tracking their history, since these files are generated from the remaining code.

I could ignore tracking these file-types, then force remove and add when pushing, but that seems inefficient. How do I best handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- create and push a tag
- associate to that tag a release, a zip archive composed of those files.

That way, you can associate a set of files to a specific version of your code.

See "[Managing releases in a repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository)" from GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. This is rather close to what I'm seeking, and a release is most likely the appropriate solution.